# How to access files in Windows partition from Ubuntu live USB?

Tags: windows, usb, files, live-usb

I run Ubuntu from a USB (run the whole OS from it, persistent) and want to access files such as my pictures or documents from Windows 7, is it possible to do so? How?

Comment: open nautilus and check your left top where it says ´devices´ for your device, Then browse your files and then u can copy/delete/move, your files

Answer (score 10):

You need to mount the partition that contains you files.
Run this on Terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It should be something like

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   209717247   104755200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

To locate which partition has your files, probably the one Windows 7 is installed in, then perform the following command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdaX /~/choose-a-folder-name-you-want
```

Where X is the number of the partition you want to mount, like /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2.

It should mount the disk with full access, so you can copy and paste files to those folders. [More about mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29).

Remember, it will mount your whole Windows 7 partition to a folder, so be carefull not to delete anything important.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It said the drive was already mounted, but there was no sign of it (or where it was mounted) in find or df.

Answer (score 1):

## Scenario B

A live boot with access to a Windows drive on a another machine.

### Fast Solution

You'll need your live-boot user `UID` and `GID`

`~ $ id`

Create a local mount directory

`~ $ mkdir ~/<mount-dir>`

`'mount'` the windows drive.

`~ $ sudo mount -t cifs -o user=<win-user-acct>,rw,uid=<uid-number>,gid=<gid-number> //<IP-of-Win-Machine>/C$ ~/<mount-dir>`

Example

`~ $ sudo mount -t cifs -o user=winUserName,rw,uid=999,gid=999 //192.168.1.77/C$ ~/winbox01`

NOTE
`'cifs-utils'` should be installed by default, but to check,

`~ $ sudo apt search cifs-utils`

[ If not installed, use the following ]

`sudo apt update && sudo install cifs-utils`

## Other Difficulties

The `'mount -o[ptions]'` list must NOT contain white space.

The following options list **will fail**,

`"-o user=winUserName[SPACE],rw,uid= ... "`

**Wired NIC Connection Issues**

`~ $ ip link`   OR   `ip address`

With NIC device name,

`~ $ sudo ip link set <NIC-dev-name> up`

**Wireless NIC Connection Issues**

`~ $ nmcli`

[ to get device name of wireless NIC ]

`~ $ nmcli d wifi list`

[ to get SSID to connect to ]

`~ $ nmcli d wifi connect <WiFiSSID> password <WiFiPassword> iface <WifiInterface>`

[ to connect NIC to Wireless network ]

**Misc**

Certain punctuation within "`<WiFiPassword>`" must be escaped,

Yes:  `\!`,`\$`,`\&`

No:    `@`, `#`

To mount the Windows `C$` share [ which is the entire drive ], your `<win-User-Acct>` will need to belong to the Windows machine's local `'Administrators'` group. If not, you'll need to share a folder on the Windows machine and use `"<IP-of-Win-Machine>/<share-name>"` in the 'mount' command.