# Neither GRUB nor Windows after a Windows Update

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

I have Windows 10 and Kubuntu 14.04 in Dual Boot.

While on Windows, I choose "Update and Restart". I left and when I came back, the computer was on Kubuntu Login Screen (Probably GRUB automatic launch). I didn't log, but choose restart in order to check the Windows update.

Now instead of GRUB, I have a HP screen saying "Boot Device not Found".

With LiveCD, I can access my files.

---

[My boot-info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26133371/)

What should I do in order to retrieve the GRUB without reinstalling any OS ?

Comment: With Recommended Repair, I have this message :
"GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again."
I'm not sure if I really should create one because there is already a EFI partition.

Comment: You might find the rEFInd tool very interesting. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html

Comment: With rEFInd, I only have access to "Microsoft Recovery on RECOVERY". The messages includes "A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed. You need to use repair tools. error 0xc00000f"

Comment: Sorry for a somewhat late reaction. But you could also check the bios and check the boot options. Also, try to remove any usb (or any other ) devices connected.  It might just be that some external storage device is used as boot device. Hope that might help. Otherwise it sounds like there is a very serious problem that might be very hard to solve. Conclusion might then be to backup important files (which is always a good thing to do) and accept the loss and reinstall. Good luck!

Comment: I am able to launch my Kubuntu session with rEFInd, but it's really slow to boot. In GParted, the EFI Partition and Microsoft Reserved Partition have "Unknown" as file system. My Media partition is still labelled and recognised as NTFS but file system can't be read. The  SMART short self-test https://paste.ubuntu.com/26167107/ find 8 pending sectors but I never managed to fix them. I'll probably clone Kubuntu and start over. (New question : is this HDD still safe ?). Thanks for rEFInd, it's a relief to see that my Kubuntu is intact.

Comment: Looking at the smart info it looks like the disk is okay. It is somewhat misleading to read pre-fail, but that simply means the type of attribute. if the column Value (not raw_value) is below the value you see at threshold, then there is a problem. Also the when_failed is empty, so no indication some failure was ever registered. So that's all good news. It is somewhat strange that the ntfs partition is not accessible.  Check the following link to check the answer on how to mount it manually. https://askubuntu.com/questions/186791/how-to-access-files-in-windows-partition-from-ubuntu-live-usb

Comment: Nowadays I only have a virtualbox image with windows for those few times I need it. When I used dual boot I used 2 separate physical disks and choose what to boot using the option provided by the bios (on my machine its F12). Even when using grub for dual boot, windows can have its own disk which it can use to install its bootloader. I always liked the idea I could just disable (or even detach) one of the disks to make sure it isn't affected. Good luck starting over and hopefully without loosing any personal data.

Comment: ps. The Current_Pending_Sector means these sectors will be remapped to spare sectors and are then marked (so they won't be used anymore). Even though this is a critical parameter, looking at the value and threshold it doesn't look like this is something critical at the moment. But, a full disk check is of course recommended to make sure. I would recommend `badblocks`. check for more info: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/badblocks.8.html and/or  http://tech.chandrahasa.com/2013/06/09/ubuntu-check-disk-for-bad-blocks-and-errors/

Answer (score 0):

From experience it seems windows updates are becoming more destructive nowadays. This is something that happens to many people and you can easily find information to resolve it. Try the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Good luck!